# XCode Archive Failed

Tags: iphone, xcode, distribution, profile

IPhone Distribution profile is showing up but its grayed out and I can select it, under it, it say profile bundle identifier does not match, yet I've checked it multiply times, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check your bundle identifier in your plist file. I am sure It is mistake with the bundle Identifier . Take care about the Case sense

Comment: I literally copied it from the apple site

Comment: It may help you ,Clean and run the project and restart the Xcode .